# How to test "Model.valid?" on a FactoryBot generated model using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have created a Chatroom Model that first validates for the presence of some fields so in the controller I create the chatroom then check if it is valid by using the `.valid?` method to determine the response. Now when I created a test model using FactoryBot the test doesn't go past the `if` statement and it returns a response as if the test has finished.

Code for my action

```rb
def create
    new_chatroom = Chatroom.create(chatroom_params)
    if new_chatroom.valid?
      new_chatroom.members.create({ user_id: @current_user[:username] })
      render_response(new_chatroom, :created)
    else
      render_error_response(new_chatroom.errors, :bad_request)
    end
  end
```

Code for the factory

```rb
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :chatroom do
    topic { Faker::Lorem.unique.question }
    slug { Faker::IndustrySegments.unique.sub_sector }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    owner { Faker::Name.first_name }
    public { true }
  end
end
```

Here is my test

```rb
it "creates a new chatroom" do
      post :create, params: {
        :topic => "test chatroom",
          :slug => "code-testing",
          :description => "Testing with Rspec",
      }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    end
```

Here is the `render_response` method:

```
def render_response(resource, status)
    if block_given?
      yield(resource, status)
    else
      render json: resource, :status => status
    end
  end
```

Test failure:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
       expected the response to have status code :created (201) but it was :ok (200)
```

I get this failure and when I try to make it pass(false positive), the coverage shows the response I'm testing against is not what's actually in my action because the rest of the lines starting from the `if` statement are not covered.

Comment: in create action you should be using `new_chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)` and then `if new_chatroom.save`

Comment: Thanks, @DeepakMahakale but the test is still not passing.

Comment: That means it's not creating the record. try to debug if you have any validation errors and that all other validation tests are passing

Comment: So @DeepakMahakale, how would you test this action of mine using FactoryBot and Rspec? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What is in the method `render_response` ?

Comment: @Зелёный I have updated the question to include the it's code. Check it out

Comment: Your question has nothing with `FactoryBot`, you create a `Chatroom` by sending request to the server.

Comment: Yes, but I thought FactoryBot takes over the whole model creation in the tests. I'm still new to Rspec testing so if you have any suggestions on how to test the create action, please do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I thought FactoryBot takes over the whole model creation in the
>   tests.

No - FactoryBot just provides factories that create model instances. This is widely used as a replacement for fixtures to populate the database before tests. Unlike with fixtures this is not automatic.

Just adding FactoryBot changes absolutely nothing in your application besides the fact that the generators will create the factory file. It does not effect the behaviour of your models in any way.

When testing the creation of resources you need to test that:

1. Given valid params, then a model should be persisted to the database
2. Given valid params, then the response should be successful and point to the newly created resource.
3. Given invalid params, then a model should not be persisted to the database
4. Given invalid params, then the response should be 422 and an error page should be rendered.

You want to test this with a request spec and not a controller spec.

> Request specs provide a high-level alternative to controller specs. In
>   fact, as of RSpec 3.5, both the Rails and RSpec teams discourage
>   directly testing controllers in favor of functional tests like request
>   specs.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Chatroom creation", type: :request do

 let(:valid_params) do
   {
     chatroom: {
       topic: "test chatroom",
       slug: "code-testing",
       description: "Testing with Rspec"
     }
   }
  end

  let(:invalid_params) do
   {
     chatroom: {
       topic: ''
     }
   }
  end

  context "when the parameters are valid" do
    it "creates a new chatroom" do
      expect do
        post '/chatrooms', params: valid_params
      end.to change(Chatroom, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "returns success" do
      post '/chatrooms', params: valid_params
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    end
  end 

  context "when the parameters are invalid" do
    it "does not create a new chatroom" do
      expect do
        post '/chatrooms', params: invalid_params
      end.to_not change(Chatroom, :count)
    end

    it "returns bad entity" do
      post '/chatrooms', params: invalid_params
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end
```

Then we can address the problem with your controller which should read:

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    new_chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)
    if new_chatroom.save
      new_chatroom.members.create(user_id: @current_user[:username])
      render_response(new_chatroom, :created)
    else
      render_error_response(new_chatroom.errors, :bad_request)
    end
  end
end
```

You should never use `.valid?` to check if a record was saved to the database. It only ensures that the model level validations have passed. Not that the INSERT statement from `.create` actually created a row in the database. See [The Perils of Uniqueness Validations](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) for an example of what can happen.

While you can use `new_chatroom.persisted?` this is the common rails idiom since it gives you a variable that you can manipulate before the record is persisted.

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    new_chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)
    new_chatroom.members.new(user: current_user)
    if new_chatroom.save
      render_response(new_chatroom, :created)
    else
      render_error_response(new_chatroom.errors, :bad_request)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to test model validity in a controller spec, but rather write request specs (as suggested by the other respondent). You can test the validity of an object on the model itself like this:

```rb
context 'valid' do
  let(:chatroom) { create :chatroom }

  it { expect(chatroom).to be_valid }
end

context 'fails validation' do
  let(:chatroom) { create :chatroom, topic: nil }

  it { expect(chatroom).not_to be_valid }
end
```

Resource: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers:be_valid

But if you want to check that actual fields are validated, I recommend using shoulda matchers on the model like this:

```rb
it { should validate_presence_of :topic }
it { should validate_presence_of :slug }
```

Resource: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers